# How to extract data from XMLHttpRequest in Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The following JavaScript sends a `XMLHttpRequest` with a parameter `recipe_num` to my rails server, how do I extract the data from the controller?  I have tried `params[:recipe_num]` and `session[:recipe_num]`, both does not work.

```
function getRules(recipe_num){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open("POST", "/path/rules_json?format=json", true);
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == request.DONE){
            buildForm(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        }
    };
    request.send("recipe_num=" + recipe_num);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5.1.2,

You can get the raw data by `request.raw_post`.
If you want to use it as `params`, you should add `Content-type` header.

```
# for string
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("prev_id="+pid+"&next_id="+nid);
# for json string
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.send(JSON.stringify({ prev_id: pid }));
```

Refer file [action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L8)

```
DEFAULT_PARSERS = {
    Mime[:json].symbol => -> (raw_post) {
      data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
      data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
    }
  }
```